# AngularJS: new object not showing in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `dir-paginate` library to paginate my data on the page. The issue I am having is when I am adding a new object to the list and viewing this on the page instantly. On the controller side every thing seems to work just alright.

Here is my controller

```
      /**
       * Array of all the items
       */
      $scope.allItems = [];

$scope.postResource = function() {
        ProjectsFactory.save($scope.newProject)
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.allItems.push(data);
            console.log($scope.allItems);
            $scope.newProject = ''
            ToastService.show('Added successfully!');
          })
          .error(function(data) {
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
            console.log(data);
          });
      }
```

Notice the log I am doing right there. On the console page I can see the new object is being added to the rest of the objects. I believe the issue is occurring on the view side which looks just like this.

```
  <table class="table table-bordered  table-hover table-condensed bg-white" st-table="rowCollectionBasic">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr dir-paginate="item in allItems | filter: search.query | itemsPerPage : itemPerPage" total-items="totalProjects" current-page="currentPage">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
    <td style="width:150px">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="showEditDialog($event, item)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="deleteResource(item, $index)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="20" class="text-center">
      <dir-pagination-controls on-page-change="pageChanged(newPageNumber)" boundary-links="true"></dir-pagination-controls>
      <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-if="AjaxInProgress"></md-progress-circular>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

To see the new created object on the page, I need to either refresh the page or click somewhere else and return to the same page again.

Someone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

**Update #1**

The project service has $http

```
      // save a new resource
  save: function(data) {
    return $http({
      url: $rootScope.baseUrl + 'projects',
      method: 'POST',
      data: data
    });

  },
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use $scope.$apply();

Comment: If `ProjectsFactory.save` doesn't use $http internally then wrap the request with `$q.when(originalRequest).then()`

Comment: @Rejs Gave this a try. Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @Jim-Y I updated the post

Comment: Can you Please add your code in plunker.